# Cannot find method moveThreadToInbox((class))

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

Sometimes, when running the addon it will throw out the following error:

> Error with the add-on.
>   Run time error.
>
> Cannot find method moveThreadToInbox((class)). [line 102, function:,file:Code]

Other times, it works perfectly fine.

I have tried to handle this how Google does in the demo [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#movethreadtoinboxthread)

But still, get the same error. In fact, thinking about it... this probably isn't the best way to do it. As the query may return a subject with the same string. So I then tried to use the ID for the new mail, but that wouldn't play nicely with `moveThreadToInbox`.

The code and error messages are below:

The line of code that the error is referencing is:
`GmailApp.moveThreadToInbox(newMailSearch[0]);`

Full code section:

```
function editThreadSubject(e) {
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  var newSubject = e.formInputs.newSubject;
  var firstMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(e.messageMetadata.messageId)
    .getThread()
    .getMessages()[0];
  var oldSubject = firstMessage.getSubject();
  var thread = GmailApp.getMessageById(e.messageMetadata.messageId).getThread();
  thread.getMessages().forEach(function(message) {
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
    var messageId = message.getId();
    var email = getEmail(messageId, accessToken);
    var unencoded = Utilities.newBlob(
      Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(email.raw)
    ).getDataAsString();
    var updatedEmail = unencoded.replace(
      "Subject: " + oldSubject,
      "Subject: " + newSubject
    );
    email.raw = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(updatedEmail);
    var newMail = Gmail.Users.Messages.import(
      {
        raw: email.raw
      },
      "me",
      Utilities.newBlob(email, "message/rfc822"),
      {
        deleted: false,
        internalDateSource: "dateHeader",
        neverMarkSpam: true,
        processForCalendar: false
      }
    );
    var newMailId = newMail.id;
    var query = ["Subject:" + newSubject];
    var newMailSearch = GmailApp.search(query);
    GmailApp.moveThreadToInbox(newMailSearch[0]);
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", messageId);
  });
  var notification = CardService.newNotification().setText(
    "The subject has been updated"
  );
  var actionResponse = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNotification(notification)
    .setStateChanged(true)
    .build();
  return actionResponse;
}
```

It should insert the new mail into Gmail, delete the old mail and move the new mail in the inbox. As I said, it works some of the time so I'm stuck trying to figure out why it's not working when it doesn't!

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be fantastic and save me going prematurely bald through pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put some type of test between this `var newMailSearch = GmailApp.search(query);` and this 
    `GmailApp.moveThreadToInbox(newMailSearch[0]);` to insure that what is returned meets the approach value and or type requirements for the function.